# League of legends Tristana strategy

Tags: league-of-legends

So i've heared of using tristana her jump in teamfights to jump behind the enemy their ad/ap carry and ult them towards my team. I can definitely see the advantage in this but what im wondering is how do you get out safe again? You just used 2 of your skills to get behind their team and your team will be busy for a few seconds killing the propelled ad/ap carry. So that leaves only you vs 4 enemy champs. How do you survive/manage this situation?

Comment: IMO don't do this in teamfights: Try this only during lanephase.  As an ADC, you are WAAAY too important for the team to even think about attempting something like this.  Much too risky.  If you die even once attempting to do this in a teamfight, it's 4v5 for a minute, and a good team will capitalize by taking baron/an inhib/dragon, whatever.  In short, I think in about 95% of 5v5 situations, this is the wrong move, regardless of whether it works or not. Specially as an ADC, you should be thinking of your own positioning all the time, not diving in for kills.

Comment: Just thought of something though, this isn't so crazy if you are playing AP trist ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a pretty risky tactic, but if your team kill the enemy ADC you shot towards them quick enough, your rocket jump spell will be instantly off of cooldown, so you can jump back into your own team. You could also flash back into your team if you took that summoner spell.

> Rocket Jump | RANGE: 900 | COOLDOWN: 22 / 20 / 18 / 16 / 14 | COST: 80 mana
>
> ACTIVE: Tristana fires at the ground to propel herself to a target location, dealing magic damage and slowing surrounding units by 60% for 2.5 seconds when she lands.
>
> **On kills or assists, Rocket Jump's cooldown resets.**

It is a very risky move, however. Doing so when the enemy has hard CC can be suicidal. As with any team fight, positioning is key and keeping track of which abilities the enemy team has already used is probably a good idea.

Comment: you could also flash to safety, or if your team has a thresh who is any good he should be able to pull you back out. There are many ways to survive this, but its a risky move by nature.

Comment: Also, synergy with champions can be usefull. If you have an Alistar following you in and smashing the other 4 up, while 3 of your team kill an unprotected ADC, you'll have a nice head-start (you see what I did here?) in the fight. Or, jumping in with Kayle's ult on you. Or a Shen ulting you. There are quite a few possibilities to try out.

Comment: All very situational though. You could hope the enemy have a Lee Sin foolish enough to kick you away, etc.

Comment: It usually isn't that risky seeing as you fire anything close to the adc forward aswell. Meaning if there is another enemy close, you'll fire them away aswell leaving the back clear to run away.

Comment: this is true but they have to be between where the enemy is and where the enemy is going to get the knockback effect, given an ad carry should be at the back of the group normally this should work but may very well not work if they are spread out enough

Answer (score 7):

This is a strategy that I've seen employed mostly by AP Tristana with a Zhonya's Hourglass, sometimes to great effect. These abilities scale very well with AP, 80% and 150% respectively, and even if you don't secure the kill immediately, you can activate Zhonya's Hourglass for an extra 2.5 seconds for your team to pick it up, granting you the reset you need to safely escape, to chase a fleeing team, or to jump on another squishy target.

Comment: I was about to answer the exact same thing! +1
For AP tristana it makes more sense to do that. Since you're an ap caster you can and should act more like an assasin. Plus Zonyas Hourglass gives you a free get out of jail card. 
For any AD carry to risk getting shut down in order to kill the other ad carry is most of the times the wrong strategy. 
It's not your job to do that unless you are more than 80% certain that you;ll get away somehow.